# Declare multiple variable bindings in one line in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Is it possible to declare multiple variable bindings in one line in SML? For example, I have the following:

```ml
let
    val m1 = [1]
    val m2 = [2]
    val m3 = [3]
in
    {...}
end
```

I would like to condense this down to something like

```ml
let
    val m1 = [1], m2 = [2], m3 = [3]
in
    {...}
end
```

This syntax doesn't work, but is there a way to declare multiple variable bindings in one line like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
- let val x = 1 val y = 5 in x + y end;
val it = 6 : int
- let val x = 1 and y = 5 in x + y end;
val it = 6 : int
```

I personally find the slight abuse of `and` more readable.
However, I think the "destructuring bind" method is more common than either of these, since it's also more generally useful.

```
- let val (x, y) = (1,5) in x + y end;
val it = 6 : int
- fun f x = (x, x + 2, x + 3);
val f = fn : int -> int * int * int
- let val (x, y, z) = f 3 in x + z end;
val it = 9 : int
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a tuple and immediately destructure it.

```ml
let
  val (m1, m2, m3) = ([1], [2], [3])
in
  ...
end
```